# Which kanji and/or hiragana are used to write this snippet of Japanese that appears in the novel Gravity's Rainbow?

Tags: quotes

It purports to be a kamikaze chant, and appears near the end of the book. Being basically a *Gravity's Rainbow* nerd, I have always wanted to be able to write it out in order to impress other literary geeks. It goes:

> Hi wa Ri ni katazu,
>   Ri wa Ho ni katazu,
>   Ho wa Ken ni katazu,
>   Ken wa Ten ni katazu.

I can't make out enough of its kanji to find a match using Google, but if it's any help, it means: Injustice can not conquer principle, Principle can not conquer law, Law can not conquer power, Power cannot conquer heaven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

非【ひ】は理【り】に勝【か】たず、理【り】は法【ほう】に勝【か】たず、法【ほう】は権【けん】に勝【か】たず、権【けん】は天【てん】に勝【か】たず